# How to convert a byte array to ZIP file and download it using Java?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, download, zipinputstream

I need to write a code to convert a byte array to ZIP file and make it download in Spring MVC.

Byte array is coming from a webservice which is a ZIP file originally. ZIP file has a folder and the folder contains 2 files. I have written the below code to convert to byte array to `ZipInputStream`. But I am not able to convert into ZIP file. Please help me in this.

Here is my code.

```
ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
ZipEntry entry = null;
while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {

    String entryName = entry.getName();

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(entryName);

    byte[] byteBuff = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = zipStream.read(byteBuff)) != -1)
    {
        out.write(byteBuff, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    out.close();
    zipStream.closeEntry();
}
zipStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am presuming here that you want to write a byte array to a ZIP file. As the data sent is also a ZIP file and to be saved is also ZIP file, shouldn't be a problem.

Two steps are needed: save it on disk and return the file.

1) Save on disk part:

```
File file = new File(/path/to/directory/save.zip);
    if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(/path/to/directory/save.zip));
            outputStream.write(bytes);
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {

        }
    } else {
        // create directory and call same code
    }
}
```

2) Now to get it back and download it, you need a controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download/attachment/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getAttachmentFromDatabase(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFileName() + "\"");
    response.setContentLength(file.length);

    FileCopyUtils.copy(file as byte-array, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

I have edited the code I have, so you will have to make some changes before it suits you 100%. Let me know if this is what you were looking for. If not, I will delete my answer. Enjoy.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The input is not a zip file. I am getting a byte array of a zip file. Now i need to convert it to zip file and make it download on request.

Comment: Yes... The code i gave u presumes input is in bytearry...saves the file as zip on disk, available for for download whenevrr needed

Comment: awesome it worked thanks a lot. but one doubt in your code you are outputting to a file, Can i download the file  with out storing it in disk?

Comment: Why not give the file a random name and delete the file after download is finished. Also, please mark the answer as accepted and upmark if it worked.

Comment: I can but i need to do that on a fly rather than storing it in harddisk, just show the download option. Your help appreciated.